# jscodeshift ignoring files randomly

Tags: javascript, jscodeshift

Im trying to use jscodeshift but when I say directory to `/src` it doesn't recurse correctly. For example:

When trying `./src` I get 4 files:

```
(.venv) ./client$ jscodeshift -t ./scripts/flow-stats/coverage-transform.js --dry --ignore-pattern="**/__generated__/**" --parser="flow" ./src
Processing 4 files... 
Spawning 4 workers...

All done. 
Results: 
0 errors
0 unmodified
0 skipped
4 ok
Time elapsed: 0.721seconds
```

If I try `./src/*` I get 9 files:

```
(.venv) ./client$ jscodeshift -t ./scripts/flow-stats/coverage-transform.js --dry --ignore-pattern="**/__generated__/**" --parser="flow" ./src/*
Processing 9 files... 
Spawning 9 workers...

All done. 
Results: 
0 errors
0 unmodified
0 skipped
9 ok
Time elapsed: 0.820seconds
```

When I am more specific `./src/components/**/*` I get 64 files?

```
(.venv) ./client$ jscodeshift -t ./scripts/flow-stats/coverage-transform.js --dry --ignore-pattern="**/__generated__/**" --parser="flow" ./src/components/**/*
Processing 64 files... 
Spawning 35 workers...

All done. 
Results: 
0 errors
0 unmodified
0 skipped
64 ok
Time elapsed: 1.958seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Jscodeshift is probably using [glob patterns](https://www.malikbrowne.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-glob-patterns), which are commonly used in tools like jest for example. Try `./src/**/*` and you should get all files.

Comment: Yea so I tried that and I got 43 files which is wrong, I have more files than that in the project.